# Custom Activity doesn't show any content

Tags: android

I made a BaseActivity class to initiate menus, toolbars etc on different activities. Using the BaseActivity works as needed for the toolbar and menu, but doesn't show any additional content I want to add there - like my textView. Can you help out please?

Here's my BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout ;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle ;
private NavigationView mNavView ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());

}
protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

public void initToolbar(int toolbarId)
{
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(toolbarId);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    assert myToolbar != null;
}
public void initMenu() {
    // Stuff in here
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId() ;
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true ;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And the actual Activity extending BaseActivity:

```
public class SaunaLight extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initToolbar(R.id.custombar);
    initMenu();

    TextView sauna = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sauna);
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.activity_sauna_light;
}
}
```

So currently my TextView sauna isn't displayed - I just get a white screen.

Comment: Is you TextView in `activity_sauna_light` file?

Comment: @user5954246 Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a very stupid mistake. Turned out, my custom action bar had a weird height and it was covering the whole layout. Got it fixed! Sorry for wasting your time!